# Center button inside div, ignoring other elements

Tags: html, css, pug

I've got the following:

```
div.div
  p.paragraph
    | about 3 lines of text... (dynamic)
  button.button-i-want-to-center
    | click_me
```

I want it to look like this:

```
___________________________
| Text.....................|
| Text.....................|
| Text.....................|
|          ______          |
|         |BUTTON|         | <--- Center of div: 
|                          |      I want the button to ignore 
|                          |      the text.
|                          |
|                          |
___________________________
```

Keeping in mind that the size of the div is dynamic.

How can I achieve this? I tried flex, but didn't do the trick. Fixed margins are no good either.

Comment: 1. `display:inline-block;` 2. `margin:auto`

Comment: @csTroubled i have added an answer below, please check it

Answer (score 4):

You should use `position:absolute;` on the button `position:relative;` on the div. See this example:

```css
div{
    position:relative;
  height:180px;
  background-color:green;
    }
    
button{
    position:absolute;
    top:calc(50% - 15px);
    left:calc(50% - 50px);
    height:30px;
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>
  lines of textlines of textlines of textlines of textlines of textlines of textlines of textlines of textlines of textlines of textlines of textlines of textlines of textlines of text
</p>
<button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use ***css3 flexbox*** concept

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  }
.wrapper {
           display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
           width:100%;
           height:100%;
           background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwy2w.jpg");
           background-repeat:no-repeat;
           background-size:cover;
           
     }

    .button {
     position:absolute;
      align-self:center;
    }
p{
  color:white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <p> other texts</p>
        <button class="button">Button</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. Outer div set as `position: relative;`
2. For the div that you can to set middle, create a class with the following css:

   ```
   .center {
      position: absolute;
      margin: auto;
      top: 0; bottom: 0;
      left: 0; right: 0;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: block` & `margin: 0 auto`, like:

```
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-holder">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium, consectetur, saepe. Praesentium doloribus dolorum qui nisi rem veniam iure. Ducimus, harum, molestiae. Harum consequatur cum accusantium fugiat, reiciendis repudiandae iste!
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways to do this , but You can simply do this with `text-align:center;` or `margin:0 auto;`
see the snippet below

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-image:url("https://th3rdculture.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/dark-forest-35836-240944.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
  margin:0;
}
.wrapper {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
p{
  color:#fff;
}
button {
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p> some texts here </p>
    <p> other texts here other texts here other texts here  </p>
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
</body>
```

or you want the text left and button only centerd use `text-align:left`

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background-image:url("https://th3rdculture.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/dark-forest-35836-240944.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
  margin:0;
}
.wrapper {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  text-align:left;
}
p{
  color:#fff;
}
button {
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <p> some texts here </p>
    <p> other texts here other texts here other texts here  </p>
    <button class="button">Button</button>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wrapper{
display: flex;
justify-content : center;
}
```

or

```
wrapper{
position : relative;
}
.button{
position: absolute;
top : 50%;
left : 50%;
}
```